# I want to pass the string to another activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to pass a string to another activity through click on the `Listview`, but it says I have something wrong.The purpose is to modify the data change when the user wants just to change some words and then update to the data.

Here is the data structure.
[https://ppt.cc/f02tWx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkRBo.png)

It says : [https://ppt.cc/f8ZYKx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Pzd.png)

This is the listview on click part

```
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

           hom.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   adapter.getItem(position);
                   String title = dataSnapshot.child(String.valueOf(position)).getValue().toString();
                   Intent intent = new Intent(MeTodolist.this, MeTodolistModify.class);
                   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                   bundle.putString("title", title);
                   intent.putExtras(bundle);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   Log.e("CHANGE",title);
               }

               @Override
               public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

               }
           });
          }
      });
```

This is the modifying page.

```
  public class MeTodolistModify extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


        private String student_id,student_name,title;
        private EditText addtext;
        private Button sure;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_me_todolist_modify);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            String title = bundle.getString("title");
            student_id = intent.getStringExtra("student_id");
            student_name = intent.getStringExtra("student_name");
            createDetail();
        }

        private void createDetail(){

            final FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            final DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference("Student").child(student_id).child("event");


            sure = findViewById(R.id.sure);

            sure.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent;
                    switch (v.getId()) {
                        case R.id.sure:
                            intent = new Intent(MeTodolistModify.this, MeTodolist.class);
                            intent.putExtra("student_id", student_id );
                            intent.putExtra("student_name",student_name);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            break;
                    }

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text, in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by just few lines of code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MeTodolist.this, MeTodolistModify.class);
String title = dataSnapshot.child(String.valueOf(position)).getValue().toString();
intent.putExtra("title", title);
startActivity(intent);
Log.e("CHANGE",title);
```

**MeTodolistModify**

```
String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing Bundle with intent extra? just use one method.

```
           Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
           bundle.putString("title", title);
           intent.putExtras(bundle);
           startActivity(intent);
```

and from the receiver.

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
 if(bundle !=null)
 String title = bundle.getString("title");
```

why you are receiving these `student_id` and `student_name`. you did not pass them.

```
    student_id = intent.getStringExtra("student_id");
    student_name = intent.getStringExtra("student_name");
```